# Regex.test() is giving true false sequential?

Tags: javascript, regex

Anyone can explain me, why local **Regex** variable and non local **Regex** variable have different output.

```
var regex1 = /a|b/g;
function isAB1() {
    return regex1.test('a');
}
console.log(isAB1()); // true
console.log(isAB1()); // false
console.log(isAB1()); // true
console.log(isAB1()); // false


function isAB2() {
    var regex2 = /a|b/g;
    return regex2.test('a');
}
console.log(isAB2()); // true
console.log(isAB2()); // true
console.log(isAB2()); // true
console.log(isAB2()); // true
```

I have created a `JSFiddle` for the same [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AmitThakkar01/rxo2mft5/).

Comment: from the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) : `called multiple times on the same global regular expression instance will advance past the previous match`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You gave your regex the `g` flag which means it will globally match results. By doing so you explicitly asked your regex to keep state about its previous matches.

```
var regex1 = /a|b/g;

> regex1.lastIndex
0
> regex1.test('a');
true
> regex1.lastIndex
1
> regex1.test('a');
false
```

If you remove the `g` you will get the results you were expecting.

You can check your expressions `.lastIndex` property for when it is done matching.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Local regex2 is reinitialized every launch of isAB2, so isAB2 always returns true

Comment: Correct, it is a different regex each time.